# Can't push message to .NET client for SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I'm playing with `SignalR`, particularly with self-hosted server and .NET client. Here's the code of the hub:

```
[HubName("ChatHub")]
public sealed class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Client {Context.ConnectionId} has joined group {groupName}");

        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Client {Context.ConnectionId} has leaved group {groupName}");

        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public void Send(string groupName, string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"A message '{message}' was received for group {groupName}");

        Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).pushMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Here's the code of simple client (console application):

```
    static async Task RunClient(string groupName, HubConnection connection)
    {
        try
        {
            var proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
            proxy.On<string>("pushMessage", _ => Console.WriteLine(_));

            await connection.Start();
            await proxy.Invoke("JoinGroup", groupName);

            string message = null;
            do
            {
                message = Console.ReadLine();

                await proxy.Invoke("Send", groupName, message);
            }
            while (message != "quit");

            await proxy.Invoke("LeaveGroup", groupName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

The problem is in this line:

```
proxy.On<string>("pushMessage", _ => Console.WriteLine(_));
```

I'm expecting, that `ChatHub.Send` will *push* message to client, and fire an action to display message to console. But client receives messages only when it send something to server itself.

E.g., if I'll run two clients, the sequence will be like this:

- client A sends "1";
- client B sends "2" and receives "1" (from A);
- client A sends empty string and receives "2" (from B).

Is it possible to push message to client, without sending something to server from that client?

Comment: Dennis I tried your code and it works...I guess it's a silly problem somewhere else.Have a look at this full (working) example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b .It doesn't use groups but you can easily modify it

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @Brannon: No, I didn't. The strange thing, that similar code works within GUI client (winforms or WPF doesn't matter).

Comment: You know for certain you are successfully connecting to the server? Displaying all exceptions?